# Multiindex partial derivative higher order product rule, i.e. formula for $\partial^\alpha(fg)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, multinomial-coefficients

I want to prove the product rule for higher order partial derivatives. It is given [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) under the name "General Leibniz rule":

$$\partial^\alpha(fg)=\sum_{\beta\leq \alpha}\binom\alpha\beta(\partial^\beta f)(\partial^{\alpha-\beta}g),$$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are multiindices.

My first attempt is to make a recursion by computing (here $i$ is just an index)

$$\partial^{\alpha}\big( \partial^i(fg) \big)=\sum_{\beta\leq\alpha}\binom{\alpha}{\beta}\Big(  (\partial^{(\alpha,i)-\beta}f)(\partial^{\beta}g)+(\partial^{\beta}f)(\partial^{(\alpha,i)-\beta}g) \Big).$$

I'm not sure how to continue at this point. The index $i$ can be one of the components of the multiindex $\alpha$. I dont'see how to manage the combinatorics...

related on MathOverflow: [Multivariable Higher Order Chain Rule](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379068/multivariable-higher-order-chain-rule)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base case $\alpha=0$ is trivial. Suppose the result holds for all $|\alpha|\le k$. We will show the result for any $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ with $|\alpha| = k+1$. Let $j$ be any index where $\alpha_j$ is not zero, and put $\alpha = \alpha_j e_j + \tilde \alpha$. Without loss of generality, $\tilde \alpha\neq 0$, since if $\tilde \alpha=0$ then $\alpha = |\alpha|e_j$ and  we can use the 1D result (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) for proof). So both $\alpha_j e_j$ and $\tilde\alpha$ have length at most $k$. Then
$\let\del\partial$
\begin{align}
\del^\alpha (fg) 
&=  \del^{\alpha_j e_j} \del^\tilde \alpha(fg) \\
&= \del^{\alpha_j e_j} \sum_{\beta \le \tilde \alpha }\binom{\tilde\alpha}{\beta} \del^\beta f \del^{\tilde \alpha-\beta}g\\
&=  \sum_{\beta \le \tilde \alpha } \sum_{\gamma=0}^{\alpha_j}\binom{\tilde\alpha}{\beta} \binom{\alpha_j}{\gamma} \del^{\gamma e_j} \del^\beta f \del^{(\alpha_j - \gamma)e_j} \del^{\tilde \alpha-\beta}g \\
&=  \sum_{\substack{\beta \le \alpha \\ \beta_j = 0}} \sum_{\gamma=0}^{\alpha_j}\binom{\alpha}{\beta+ \gamma e_j}   \del^{\beta+\gamma e_j} f \del^{\alpha - (\beta + \gamma e_j)} g \\
&=
\sum_{\gamma=0}^{\alpha_j} \sum_{\substack{\delta: \delta \le \alpha \\ \delta_j = \gamma}}\binom{\alpha}{\delta}   \del^{\delta} f \del^{\alpha - \delta } g \\
&=
 \sum_{\substack{\delta \le \alpha}}\binom{\alpha}{\delta}   \del^{\delta} f \del^{\alpha - \delta } g
\end{align}
which was what we wanted.